# do I need to restart the server every time i change a resource?

Tags: java, api, jersey, grizzly

I want to know if every time I make any changes to a resource, do I need to restart the server? I am inexperienced in the area, I would like content for best practice to build an API.

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: @AndrianekenaMoise Portuguese

Comment: Try writing your questions in English for additional exposure

Comment: Sorry i didn't know! thanks for tips

Comment: Welcome, please try to describe your problems with clear question and the solution you want. It would help others if you state your `IDE`, `Server`, and `Language/framework`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IDEs hotdeploy in **debug mode** to reload your classes, in most cases, this works but when doesn't the IDE will tell you to restart the application.